# Google Earth Engine Reprojection to non-EPSG defined CRS

Tags: coordinate-system, google-earth-engine, epsg, homolosine

Is it possible to reproject an image in earth engine to non-EPSG defined coordinates? In particular either Goode Homosline (SR-ORG:7619) or Mollweide (ESRI:54009). Passing either to `.reproject()` returns an error stating that the CRS cannot be parsed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, Earth Engine can reproject images to non-EPSG coordinate reference systems.

Earth Engine uses the Java [GeoTools](http://www.geotools.org/) library for coordinate system transformations which supports the [Coordinate System Well-Known Text (WKT)](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/javadocs/org/opengis/referencing/doc-files/WKT.html) format, and a set of base projections.

### Mollweide

The [ESRI:54009](http://spatialreference.org/ref/esri/54009/) World [Mollweide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollweide_projection) coordinate reference system (CRS) has a [WKT representation](http://spatialreference.org/ref/esri/54009/prettywkt/) that includes a base projection entry    `PROJECTION["Mollweide"]` that is supported by GeoTools. The following Earth Engine code shows how to reproject to World Mollweide:

```js
// Get a sample image (Landsat 8) which uses a UTM projection.
var image = ee.Image('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA/LC08_044034_20170614');

// Get the bounding coordinates of the Landsat image.
var bounds = image.geometry().bounds().getInfo()['coordinates'];

print('Original image (UTM) URL:',
  image.getThumbURL({
    bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],
    min: 0,
    max: 0.3,
    dimensions: '400'
  })
);

// Project the image to Mollweide.
var wkt = ' \
  PROJCS["World_Mollweide", \
    GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984", \
      DATUM["WGS_1984", \
        SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137,298.257223563]], \
      PRIMEM["Greenwich",0], \
      UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]], \
    PROJECTION["Mollweide"], \
    PARAMETER["False_Easting",0], \
    PARAMETER["False_Northing",0], \
    PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",0], \
    UNIT["Meter",1], \
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","54009"]]';

var proj_mollweide = ee.Projection(wkt);
var image_mollweide = image.reproject({
  crs: proj_mollweide,
  scale: 300
});

print('Projected image (World Mollweide) URL:',
  image_mollweide.getThumbURL({
    bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],
    min: 0,
    max: 0.3,
    region: bounds,
    dimensions: '400'
  })
);
```

*(Link to the code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/5b50ad250e83ec994335615c4db72a00)*

The original image in a UTM projection looks like:
[image]

While the World Mollweide projected images looks like:
[image]

### Goode Homosline

By contrast the [SR-ORG:7619](http://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/7619/) (Interrupted Goode Homosline) has a [CRS WKT](http://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/7619/prettywkt/) that includes a base projection entry `PROJECTION["Interrupted_Goode_Homolosine"]` that is not supported by GeoTools, so it is not supported by Earth Engine.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent and very comprehensive answer Tyler! That's perfect. Legend!

Comment: @tyler-erickson seems like this approach [fails](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/415624/34438) with Equal Earth projection, despite supprt in GeoTools

Comment: Is there any way to know whether a base projection is supported by GeoTools, besides trial-and-error in GEE? Thanks!

Comment: You can copy WKT strings from https://projectionwizard.org/