# Homolosine projection with GeoTools

Tags: geotools, homolosine

I would like to use Goode's Homolosine projection with GeoTools. This projection is fully supported by both PROJ and GDAL. However, when I try to create a `CoordinateReferenceSystem` object with this projection, GeoTools complains it has no transformation. For instance, the following little programme:

```
import org.geotools.referencing.CRS;
import org.geotools.referencing.crs.DefaultGeographicCRS;
import org.opengis.referencing.crs.CoordinateReferenceSystem;
import org.opengis.referencing.operation.MathTransform;

public class WGS84toHomolosine 
{
    static CoordinateReferenceSystem WORLDCRS = DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84;
    static String wkt = "PROJCS[\"Homolosine\",\n" + 
                        "    GEOGCS[\"WGS 84\",\n" + 
                        "        DATUM[\"WGS_1984\",\n" + 
                        "            SPHEROID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563,\n" + 
                        "                AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"7030\"]],\n" + 
                        "   AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"6326\"]],\n" + 
                        "        PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n" + 
                        "            AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"8901\"]],\n" + 
                        "        UNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433,\n" + 
                        "            AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"9122\"]],\n" + 
                        "        AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"4326\"]],\n" + 
                        "    PROJECTION[\"Interrupted_Goode_Homolosine\"],\n" + 
                        "    UNIT[\"Meter\",1]]";
    static CoordinateReferenceSystem crs;
    static MathTransform transform;

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try 
        {
            crs = CRS.parseWKT(wkt);
            transform = CRS.findMathTransform(WORLDCRS, crs, true);
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println(transform.toWKT());
        System.out.println(transform.getClass().getCanonicalName());
    }
}
```

Regurgitates this output:

```
org.opengis.referencing.NoSuchIdentifierException: No transform for classification "Interrupted_Goode_Homolosine".
    at org.geotools.referencing.operation.DefaultMathTransformFactory.lambda$getProvider$1(DefaultMathTransformFactory.java:267)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:290)
    at org.geotools.referencing.operation.DefaultMathTransformFactory.getProvider(DefaultMathTransformFactory.java:264)
    at org.geotools.referencing.operation.DefaultMathTransformFactory.getDefaultParameters(DefaultMathTransformFactory.java:297)
    at org.geotools.referencing.wkt.Parser.parseProjection(Parser.java:632)
    at org.geotools.referencing.wkt.Parser.parseProjCS(Parser.java:988)
    at org.geotools.referencing.wkt.Parser.parseCoordinateReferenceSystem(Parser.java:232)
    at org.geotools.referencing.wkt.Parser.parseCoordinateReferenceSystem(Parser.java:212)
    at org.geotools.referencing.factory.ReferencingObjectFactory.createFromWKT(ReferencingObjectFactory.java:1068)
    at org.geotools.referencing.CRS.parseWKT(CRS.java:560)
    at org.isric.WGS84toHomolosine.main(WGS84toHomolosine.java:32)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.isric.WGS84toHomolosine.main(WGS84toHomolosine.java:41)
```

What is amiss here? Could there be something wrong with my system set up that would prevent GeoTools from finding PROJ's database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/272818/google-earth-engine-reprojection-to-non-epsg-defined-crs) the Interrupted_Goode_Homolosine is not (yet) supported by GeoTools.