# Google Earth Engine Reprojection to Interrupted Goode Homolosine

Tags: coordinate-system, google-earth-engine, homolosine

There was a [great answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/273213/166347) to [Google Earth Engine Reprojection to non-EPSG defined CRS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/272818/115) about the support of Interrupted Goode  Homolosine projection in GEE.

It seems that since [release 22.3](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/pull/2830) the Homolosine projection is now available in GeoTools. However when I try in Google Earth Engine I get the error `Projection: The CRS of a map projection could not be parsed`. No problems with Mollweide.

The code I am running is [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/210e0cadad592078377df2e31227d0a5?noload=true).

```
// Get a sample image (Landsat 8) which uses a UTM projection.
var image = ee.Image('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA/LC08_044034_20170614');

// Get the bounding coordinates of the Landsat image.
var bounds = image.geometry().bounds().getInfo()['coordinates'];

print('Original image (UTM) URL:',
  image.getThumbURL({
    bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],
    min: 0,
    max: 0.3,
    dimensions: '400'
  })
);

// Project the image to Mollweide.
var wkt = ' \
  PROJCS["World_Mollweide", \
    GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984", \
      DATUM["WGS_1984", \
        SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137,298.257223563]], \
      PRIMEM["Greenwich",0], \
      UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]], \
    PROJECTION["Mollweide"], \
    PARAMETER["False_Easting",0], \
    PARAMETER["False_Northing",0], \
    PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",0], \
    UNIT["Meter",1], \
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","54009"]]';


var igh = ' \
  PROJCS["Homolosine", \
    GEOGCS["WGS 84", \
        DATUM["WGS_1984", \
            SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563, \
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]], \
   AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]], \
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0, \
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]], \
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433, \
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]], \
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]], \
    PROJECTION["Interrupted_Goode_Homolosine"], \
    UNIT["Meter",1]]';

var proj_mollweide = ee.Projection(wkt);
var image_mollweide = image.reproject({
  crs: proj_mollweide,
  scale: 300
});


var proj_igh = ee.Projection(igh);
var image_igh = image.reproject({
  crs: proj_igh,
  scale: 300
});
```

Is the GeoTool version used in GEE less recent than the one integrating this projection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is the GeoTools version used in GEE less recent than the one integrating this projection?

Yes.

If you have a need for this projection, you can request it at [Google Earth Engine's issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=184406&template=719602). Please make sure to describe how it would be useful to you; it would also be useful to mention that it is available in newer GeoTools.