# Equal Earth Projection in Google Earth Engine

Tags: coordinate-system, google-earth-engine, equal-earth-projection

I'm trying to get a gobal visualization similar to [what NASA does](https://svs.gsfc.nasa.gov/4945). They are probably using popular [Equal Earth projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equal_Earth_projection) ([EPSG:8857](https://epsg.io/8857)), but this fails in GEE.

In order to implement this projection, I tried following [this guide](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/273213/34438). It mentions that a base projection must be supported by GeoTools, [which is the case](https://docs.geotools.org/latest/javadocs/org/geotools/referencing/operation/projection/EqualArea.html).
However, mentioned approach failed with this wkt definition:

```
var countries = ee.FeatureCollection("USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017");
var countries_image = ee.Image().byte().paint(countries).visualize({palette: 'black'});
var aoiBounds = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([-179.0, -89.0, 179.0, 89.0], 'EPSG:4326', false);

var equalearth_wkt = ' \
  PROJCS["WGS 84 / Equal Earth Greenwich", \
    GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984", \
      DATUM["WGS_1984", \
        SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137,298.257223563]], \
      PRIMEM["Greenwich",0], \
      UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]], \
    PROJECTION["EqualArea"], \
    PARAMETER["False_Easting",0], \
    PARAMETER["False_Northing",0], \
    PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",0], \
    UNIT["Meter",1], \
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","8857"]]';    


var proj_equalarea = ee.Projection(equalearth_wkt);
var countries_equalarea = countries_image.reproject({
  crs: proj_equalarea,
  scale: 10000
});

print('Projected image (Equal Area) URL:',
  countries_equalarea.getThumbURL({
    region: aoiBounds,
    dimensions: '400'
  })
);
```

This returns an error:

```
Projection: The CRS of a map projection could not be parsed.
```

Here's [a link to the full code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/63a846bf48be49a9174bb3a79143d6a5).

Am I doing something wrong, or there's no support for Equal Area projection in GEE, despite support in underlying GeoTools?

Comment: Could you share how you try to use the projection and what error it gives?

Comment: I attached it as a link below the question, here it is: https://code.earthengine.google.com/63a846bf48be49a9174bb3a79143d6a5

Comment: Links tend to break at some point, better to have all information in the question

Comment: @JonasV I updated the question to include complete code with an error

Comment: I think `PROJECTION['EqualArea']` is the problem. It may be something different.

Comment: I have noticed that for every wkt the PROJECTION[''] has different names. For instance, [US National Atlas Equal Area (EPSG: 2163)](https://epsg.io/2163) has the PROJECTION["Lambert_Azimuthal_Equal_Area"].

Comment: I have tried using 'Equal_Earth' but didn't work. Either it is not supported by Earth Engine or some other name is allotted for it.

Comment: It might be, that the GeoTools version Earth Engine is running does not yet have the EqualArea projection available, but you could request an upgrade at the issue tracker. See this answer here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/374844/google-earth-engine-reprojection-to-interrupted-goode-homolosine

Comment: Any news on this question? I am having the same problem